# Given array, write a function and return a boolean value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a function called, `shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, candy)`.
The function should find the candy in the array that matches the name passed in.
When that candy is found, return `true` if the number inStock is less than the weeklyAverage.
Otherwise return `false`.
If the array doesn't have any candy with that name, return `false`.

Given array:

```
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];
```

What I have so far (I'm new to JS):

```js
function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, candy) {
  for (let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    if (inventory.inStock < inventory.weeklyAverage) {
      return true;
    } 
    else if (inventory.includes(inventory.candy)) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, "Twizzlers"); //->  true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the corrected logic that using OP's approach:

```js
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];

function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, candy) {
  // loop through the inventory
  for (let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
  
    // if the current candy(inventory[i]) is the candy we are looking for, step in
    // otherwise, skip this candy and continue the next iteration
    if(inventory[i].candy === candy) {
    
      // check the stock
      if (inventory[i].inStock < inventory[i].weeklyAverage) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // if didn't find the candy
  return false;
}

console.log(shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, "Twizzlers"));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, your pseudocode makes is very understandable and I appreciate that. Thank you Hao!!

Comment: you do something like `if (condition==true) return true; else return false`. `return condition` is enough

Comment: @MisterJojo  I think this is clearer to understand, so I keep it the verbose way for better readability for a beginner. But yes, you're right. It can be just `return inventory[i].inStock < inventory[i].weeklyAverage`

Answer (score 0):

On your code, there is no part to find the item of `inventory` which has same `candy` name.

First, you should find the item with the input `candy` name and get the result from that item.

This can be done using [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];

function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, candy) {
  const existed = inventory.find((item) => item.candy === candy);
  if (existed && existed.inStock < existed.weeklyAverage) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, "Twizzlers"));
```

Comment: Derek, thank you for finding a working solution! I wasn't sure which part I was missing but I now understand. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Derek's answer, remove the if condition since it is not necessary.

```
const inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];

function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, candy) {
  const existed = inventory.find(item => item.candy === candy);
  return existed && existed.inStock < existed.weeklyAverage;
}

console.log(shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, "Twizzlers"));
```

Comment: Great to know the condition isn't even necessary. This is an awesome and efficient working answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just use [array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let inventory = 
    [ { candy: 'Twizzlers',       inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 } 
    , { candy: 'Sour Patch Kids', inStock:  90, weeklyAverage: 100 } 
    , { candy: 'Milk Duds',       inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 } 
    , { candy: 'Now and Laters',  inStock: 150, weeklyAverage:  40 } 
    ] 

function shouldWeOrderThisCandy( arr, candy )
  {
  return arr.some(x=>x.candy===candy && x.inStock < x.weeklyAverage)
  }

console.log('Twizzlers ->', shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, 'Twizzlers')) // true
console.log('Milk Duds ->', shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, 'Milk Duds')) // false
console.log('xxx       ->', shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, 'xxx'))       // false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer, and over my head. Thank you for editing my question and giving me a working solution!

Comment: @alexwhitmore  you're welcome, this is just some practice, you will get it too ;)

Answer (score 0):

FYI. This worked for me (after several hours grinding it) for future beginner Javascript pupils:

```js
function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, candy) {
  for(let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    if(inventory[i].candy === candy) {
      if(inventory[i].inStock < inventory[i].weeklyAverage) {
      return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else if(candy.length <= 0 ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  if(inventory.candy !== candy) {
    return false;
  }
}
```